# TikZ External Creating Border Around Image

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics, includegraphics

I am using TikZ with the `external` package to export a drawing as a pdf, and include in another LaTeX document.

Here is the code that creates the image:

```
% test_figure.tex
% exports a pdf named test_figure-figure0.pdf

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{external}

\tikzexternalize

\begin{document}

\tikzset{external/force remake}

\begin{tikzpicture}
[node distance = 1cm, every node/.style={node distance=2cm},
% Some style settings
group/.style={rectangle, draw, fill=black!10, inner sep=5pt, text width=4cm, 
text badly centered, minimum height=1.2cm}] 

% Draw Two Boxes
\node [group] (box1) {Box 1};
\node [group,below of = box1] (box2) {Box 2)};

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

This next .tex file uses the `graphics` package to display the pdf:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphics}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}

\centering
\caption{PDF Exported from Previous Tikz External Command}

\frame{\includegraphics{test_figure-figure0.pdf}}

\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

The result is an image that has an unintended border.

[image: screenshot of document]

Moreover, if I use `trim` to erase the border, I will also cut into the image itself. Is there a way to avoid having this border on my image?

One approach is to make the original drawing slightly bigger than its contents and then trim back that extra bordering. I'm open to solutions of that flavor, but if there is a cleaner solution, even better.

Comment: I guess it results from the insertion mode with \frame. Leaving out this command may insert the pic without a frame around.

Answer (score 1):

As explained by @harald-lichenstein, the problem is that I'm using the `\frame` command. Once that is taken out, the border goes away:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphics}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}

\centering
\caption{PDF Exported from Previous Tikz External Command}

\includegraphics{test_figure-figure0.pdf}

\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image: Screen Capture of Document]